# JQuery - Replace quotes with html escape

Tags: javascript, jquery

A table shows data grabbed from a database on my site, when a button is clicked the "enableEditing" function is called using the onclick attribute. Then for one field for each row in the the table, an input textbox appears using the field as the value, and the key as the input name.

**Before:**

```
<tr class="data_row">
    <td class="property_cell">project ref</td>
    <td class="myNumber">200407</td>
</tr>
```

**After:**

```
<tr class="data_row">
    <td class="property_cell">project ref</td>
    <td class="myNumber">
        <input name="project ref" value="200407">
    </td>
</tr>
```

**jQuery:**

```
function enableEditing(){

    $("#object_data tr").each(function(){
        var key = $(this).children(".property_cell").html();
        var value = $(this).children(".myNumber").text();
        $(this).children(".myNumber").html("<input name='" + key + "' value='" + value + "'>");
    });
}
```

This works fine, however some of the data from the database contains speech marks or single quotes, which when changed to an input field will mess up the input html. How can I escape the html for each input field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways. One of the less error-prone ones is to make jQuery/DOM do the escaping:

```
var input = $('<input name="'+key+'">');
input.val(value);
$(this).children(".myNumber").empty().append(input);
```

Comment: That worked great, however I noticed the input value does not appear in the source / Google inspector. Can the data within the input field still be manipulated? For example, updating the database from which the original value was grabbed

Comment: DOM inspector features of browsers should display the value even though we added it dynamically (some inspectors are broken, though, e.g. Developer Tools in some versions of Internet Explorer). In any case, it should make no difference in actual operation, though I'm not quite sure what exactly you were asking. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('.myNumber').contents().replaceWith(function(){
    return $('<input />', { name: $(this).parent().prev().text(), value : $(this).text()});
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WY7EH/)

Comment: Not quite - doesn't get the `name` attribute from the other cell.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using `.html()` for something like this. In fact, just don't use jQuery. [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) is vastly superior - jQuery is entirely built using it!

```
var rows = document.getElementById('object_data').rows, l = rows.length, i, td, inp;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    td = rows[i].cells[1];
    if( !td.className.match(/\bmyNumber\b/)) continue; // failsafe
    inp = document.createElement('input');
    inp.type = "text";
    inp.name = rows[i].cells[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    inp.value = td.firstChild.nodeValue;
    td.replaceChild(inp,td.firstChild);
}
```

While it may seem like more code, it will run at least an order of magnitude, possibly two or three, faster than the jQuery alternative.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wWfsM/)
[jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/table-to-input)

Comment: I didn't downvote. I would be willing to use vanilla JS if it were my project, however one of the specifications it to use jQuery :/

Comment: That's a stupid specification. Honestly, if I were given such a restriction, I would ask "do you WANT customers to use your site? Or do you want them to get fed up with how slow it is and tell their friends how much it sucks?"

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if this is merely one dynamic feature of the page, next to some much more complex ones that are going to be extremely painful in vanilla JS, the overhead is negligible.

Comment: @JanKrüger Vanilla JS is not painful. If it is, then you haven't assembled the right tools. Imagine you have a task, to hammer a nail in a wall. What you're describing is like hitting it with the palm of your hand - it'll work, but it'll hurt like hell. jQuery is like taking a swiss-army sledgehammer to it. My solution would be to build a hammer out of the many materials available, and use that.

Comment: @Kolink that is, of course, a valid solution. We happen to prefer different solutions, apparently. Personally I like swiss-army sledgehammers.

Comment: @JanKrüger And that is entirely your preference ^_^ Personally, I'd rather sacrifice more effort on my part in order to give the users a much faster site.

Comment: Yes, it's my preference. That's why I said so. ;) Anyway, after jQuery has been loaded, the additional overhead in execution time really only becomes noticeable if you update many, many elements in a loop (the way benchmarks and overly complex code do it, for instance). For updating a handful of elements in response to what seems to be explicit user action, I don't think there'd be a perceptible difference.

Comment: I can tell you there is :p My rival website "proudly" displays page load times, and it frequently says times in the realm of "generated in 37ms, downloaded in 500ms and rendered in 7000ms", whereas my jQuery-free site displays "generated in 28ms, downloaded in 300ms and rendered in 200ms" ;)